# Windows 10 Home: How to log in when ProfSvc is deactivated

Tags: windows, windows-10

by some "mistake" ProfSvc has been deactivated on a Windows 10 Home system (German), so that logging in results in 'Fehler bei der Anmeldung des Dienstes "ProfSvc".' which translates to something like 'The User Profile Service failed the logon'. The Windows 10 Home system resides on C:\Windows.

I can boot a Win10PE flash drive on that computer that can access drive C:. How can I (re-)activate the ProfSvc? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried booting into safe mode? You can check services,msc then. https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried to load safe mode but came to a halt when Windows presents me with a message "you need a new app to open ms-get-started". The ok button is disabled. Clicking with the mouse somewhere just leaves a black screen with a mouse pointer.

Comment: boot in repair options, open cmd.exe, run [regedit.exe, load the offline registry hive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdy9w3DCBSY) "C:\Windows\System32\config\system" and change the start value of the service ProfSvc from 4 to 2.

Comment: @JohnGalt you could try alt-f4 at that screen to get past it.

Comment: @Stese Thanks, but Alt+F4 does not get any reaction. I tried Ctrl+Alt+Del and try to log in with another user account but after a fatal exception error without further explanation the cursor is now rotating endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem described I ended up in a message "Ruhezustand wird vorbereitet" meaning "PC goes to hibernation mode". I was able to solve the problem following this procedure:

1. Reboot the system and turn if off by power-button as soon as the Windows logo is displayed.
2. Repeat the procedure in 1 until message "starting repair mode" (or similar [display time was too short to read properly])
3. System conducted a harddisk check (everything was fine)
4. System booted into repair mode. There I selected to go back to the latest restore point.